# How to create layout

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to create an android app which consist of a following list which has capability to expand once a user clicks on particular row.

I have already integrated an ExpandedListView to it. But there is  a problem with that.

If i press on a EditText the focus wont stay, it appears there are some common issue on that scenario.

Is there is any layout structure which i can use rather than a expanded list view.

Here is the screenshot of my app

[image]

Thanks

Comment: take a loot at https://github.com/hamsterready/android-accordion-view

Comment: @BasimSherif i tried to open the app . but it didn't are u sure its working

Comment: Yes I have already used that library in my app.What error u getting?

Comment: Sorry . thanks. i got it . its a big relief . i was stucked with the expandablelistview

Comment: Can you accpet it if I post as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a loot at [here](http://github.com/hamsterready/android-accordion-view) .Its a best alternative library for Expandable listview.And you will have many customization options.